# Conflict between SKScene and dismissViewControllerAnimated

Tags: modalviewcontroller, sprite-kit

I have 4 VC's in my app- Main -> Game -> End and Main ->Settings.

When I go from Game to Main, or from End to Main, the SKScene in main is appeared as paused, though it isn't (confirmed by an NSLog)- it appears as in a middle of one of the actions that the SKScene usually executes.

When I go from Settings to Main, the SKScene in main works!

What is this kind of sorcery?

Thanks!

Comment: do you mean the scene is paused during the transition, or does it remain paused after the transition? When you say confirmed, how did you confirm that?

Comment: It only appears paused. The NSLog says scene.paused = NO, but it appears paused. Again, *appears*.

Comment: From what I've seen, the scene will be paused during a segue transition. But after that the scene should run normally. Does it do that? If not and it keeps being "paused" this may be a bug in your code, perhaps you're stopping the actions and you assume they are paused.

Comment: Also, the scene has no paused property, unless you added one. The view has: self.scene.view.paused. Maybe you were logging the wrong paused flag?

Comment: SKScene is a sub-class of SKNode, so it has the property paused

Comment: Ah, didn't check the node. Still, both view and node/scene can be paused, plus actions can be stopped/removed and their speed/duration changed.

Comment: Okay this is just weird. It now only happens when the End VC has been loaded. And loading settings VC fixes this. ME, Y U NO NO TO DEBUG :(